# How to wait for onTransitionEnd in react testing library

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I've got an element with a `transitionend` event listener attached, and this triggers a function if the transition event that ended was for the `margin-left` property. I'm unable to assert this function is being triggered which I assume is because I'm not able to mock or wait for the transition to finish. Here's a snippet of the code:

index.tsx

```
<div onTransitionEnd={onTransitionEnd} style={{transition: 'margin-left 0.5s'}} />

const onTransitionEnd = (e: TransitionEvent) => {
  if (e.propertyName === 'margin-left') {
    action();
  }
};

const action = () => {
  console.log('here');
};
```

index.rtl.test.tsx

```
fireEvent.transitionEnd(element, { propertyName: 'margin-left' });
expect(action).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

The `transitionend` event listener is being called but the `propertyName` property isn't being registered. Any ideas how I can trigger this transition or wait for it to finish?

Comment: Could you try changing the `margin-left` attribute to trigger the transition and wait for it to fire instead?